# Problem with the proof of fhe Peano Existence Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

[image: Peano Theorem][image]

I everyone, here there is the proof of the Peano Theorem, but I don't understand when the book says

> Now Let $K$ be so large that for all $k>K$, $$\mid \varphi (x) - \varphi^{(k)}(x)\mid <M\eta$$ and all links of the polygonal arc $L_{k}$ have length less than $\eta$. Then if $\mid x' - x\mid < 2\eta$, all the Euler polygons $y=\varphi^{(k)}(x)$ for which $k>K$ lie entirely in the interior of $Q$.

The first inquality makes sense since $$\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty}\varphi^{(k)}(x)=\varphi (x),$$
and also the fact that every link has length less than $\eta$ by the construction of $L_{k}$. My problem is that I can't see why with this hypothesis $\mid y'-y\mid < 4M\eta$.
Can someone help me? Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By construction, the Euler polygons consist of straight line segments with gradient $<M$.  This limits the y-variation of the polygon for a given x-variation.  We also have a condition limiting how far from $y'$ the polygon passes when $x=x'$.

Putting these together,
$$\mid y'-y\mid = \mid \varphi(x')-\varphi^{(k)}(x)\mid$$
$$\le\; \mid \varphi(x')-\varphi^{(k)}(x')\mid + \mid \varphi^{(k)}(x')-\varphi^{(k)}(x)\mid$$
$$\lt M\eta + M\mid x'-x\mid$$
$$= M\eta +2M\eta$$
$$\lt 4M\eta$$

It would probably help to draw a picture at this point!